# I can't test fail case

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

Here is my service method

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LocationServiceImpl implements LocationService {

    private final LocationRepository locationRepository;

    public LocationMobieDTO getLocationById(HttpHeaders headers, String locationId) {
        credentialService.checkRegistered(headers);
        Location location = locationRepository.findById(locationId).orElseThrow(() -> {
            KafkaMessageDTO<String> messageDTO = KafkaMessageDTO.<String>builder().id(locationId).build();
            messageServiceString.sendMessage(
                KafkaTopics.TEST.topic,
                messageServiceString.prepareMsg(ResponseEnum.UNKNOWN_LOCATION, messageDTO)
            );
            return new CustomException(ResponseEnum.UNKNOWN_LOCATION);
        });
        return mapper.mapperLocationToDTO(location);
    }
```

Here is my test case

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class LocationServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private LocationServiceImpl locationService;

    @Mock
    private LocationRepository locationRepository;

    @Test
    void whenGetLocationById_thenReturnCustomException() {
        // Given
        when(locationRepository.findById(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());

        // When 
        CustomException exception = assertThrows(CustomException.class, () -> {
            locationService.getLocationById(headers, anyString());
        });

        // Then
        assertEquals(ResponseEnum.UNKNOWN_LOCATION, exception.getException());
    }
}
```

Here is Controller

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/{country_code}/{party_id}/{location_id}")
    public Response<LocationMobieDTO> getLocationById(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @PathVariable("location_id") String locationId){
        
        return Response.<LocationMobieDTO>builder()
                .data(locationService.getLocationById(headers, locationId))
                .statusCode(ResponseEnum.SUCCESS.getStatusCode())
                .statusMessage(ResponseEnum.SUCCESS.getStatusMessage())
                .timestamp(Instant.now().toString()).build();
    }
```

Here is Error

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==] expected: [com.demo.myapi.exception.CustomException] but was: [java.lang.NullPointerException]
 at com.demo.myapi.location.service.LocationServiceTest.whenGetLocationById_thenReturnCustomException(LocationServiceTest.java:177)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.demo.myapi.location.service.LocationServiceImpl.lambda$0(LocationServiceImpl.java:95)
 at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
 at com.demo.myapi.location.service.LocationServiceImpl.getLocationById(LocationServiceImpl.java:91)
 at com.demo.myapi.location.service.LocationServiceTest.lambda$0(LocationServiceTest.java:178)
 ... 72 more
```

I expect that return CustomException but returns NullPointerException instate. I have tried to mock lick this `when(locationRepository.findById(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());` too but it also didn't work. Also I replaced `anyString` with random string and didn't work.
When I debug, test is failing in here `Location location = locationRepository.findById(locationId).orElseThrow` but I already want that test fails over there becuase I am trying to test when there is no record in the DB regarding the location ID.

Is there a way that I test this without change source code?

Comment: Use `.thenReturn(Optional.absent())`. Methods with the return type `Optional` should never return `null`. If you return `null` then your code will try to call `.orElseThrow()` on a `null` reference, which will throw the NPE.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I can't use that because I do not have `absent()` in my Optional (java.utils) and I want to test `.orElseThrow()` section.

Comment: Then use `Optional.empty()`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have tried that but still I have NPE

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I misremembered which one the Java optional has, `empty()` is the correct one. If that still produces a NPE, then please [edit] your question to include the new code **and** the complete stack trace of the failure.

Comment: @JoachimSauer FYI - edited the question and added more details

Comment: Your code is incomplete, as there's no definition of `messageServiceString` anywhere. And I suspect that for one reason or another that is `null` during your test execution. Just check line 95 of `LocationServiceImpl` to see where it throws the exception.

Comment: @JoachimSauer you were right. Thank you so much. That started to work after mocking `messageServiceString` and removed `when(locationRepository.findById(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());`

Comment: Your code is still not correct - you should not be using argument matchers when calling method under test: `assertThrows(CustomException.class, () -> {
            locationService.getLocationById(headers, anyString());
        });`

Comment: @Lesiak If so, how can I test `assertEquals(ResponseEnum.UNKNOWN_LOCATION, exception.getException());`? Also, How should be best case in your opinion for that test case?